# If I download Steam on Ubuntu, does that mean I can play any game I get on steam ON ubuntu?

Tags: games, steam

This question may or may not be very stupid, as I am kind of ignorant when it comes to computers.  My friend has convinced me to switch to Linux, and I'm trying to figure out how I can game on it.

Comment: You can play any game that is linux-compatible that you have bought or is free.

Comment: is that basically your question?

Answer (score 4):

Any game? No.

From the native Linux client you can only play the games that have Linux releases. In my case this is 86/182 games. Those that are there work well but if you're curious about any one game, go to its Steam page and that should tell you if it has a Linux release or not.

For the others you can install the Windows version of Steam under Wine. This is a compatibility layer which will allow you to play *most* things. Sometimes with some kicking and screaming, sometimes not at all.

**Edit**: Linux games in *my* library has gone from 86/182 to 129/230 in the 6 months since I wrote this. There are [*many* more out there](http://steamdb.info/linux/) that I don't yet own.

Answer (score 1):

If you download Steam, and install it, and log into your Steam account, you can play any Linux-compatible games on Ubuntu.

There are games that are Linux-compatible, and you will be restrained to playing those.

You also only be able to play games that you buy or are free, but I am assuming you already know that.

There are many games on steam that won't work on Linux, but also there are many that will.

You can browse Linux-compatible steam games here: http://store.steampowered.com/browse/linux/